# Replace numpy array with another array according to a mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have two numpy arrays `A` and `B` and a mask `mask` of booleans (True/False), all of identical dimensions. I want to replace the elements in `A` with those of `B` where the corresponding element of `mask` is `True`; where the corresponding element of mask is `False` I want to retain the original element of `A`. How can I do this?

Example:

```
# Input
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
B = A*10
mask = np.array([[True, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, False, True]])

# Output
desired_output = np.array([[0, 10, 2], [3, 40, 5], [6, 7, 80]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
In [54]: A[mask]=B[mask]
In [55]: A
Out[55]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  2],
       [ 3, 40,  5],
       [ 6,  7, 80]])
```

`np.putmask(A,mask,B)` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `map`

```
def repl(a,b,m):
    return b if m else a

desired_output = list(map(repl,A,B,mask))
```